# Contradiction in Alternating Harmonic Series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

$$R_1=a\cos(30°) ,R_2=2a\cos(30°),.... R_n=na\cos(30°)=\frac{\sqrt{3}na}{2}$$

Find the sum of $$\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}-\frac{1}{R_4}+\frac{1}{R_5}....... \infty\right)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{R_n}\right)$$

So I proceed as
Let required sum is $kS$ then,
$k=\cfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}a}$
$$S=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}....\infty\right)$$
$$\implies S=\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)$$

$$\implies S=\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)$$

$$\implies S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)$$

$$\implies S=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}+....\frac{\infty}{2}\right)$$

$$\implies S=\frac{1}{2}S \implies S=kS=0$$

The sum by Taylor series is $\cfrac{2\ln(2)}{\sqrt{3} a}$

But since $\infty\div 2=\infty$,  I don't see why my method is wrong. I know infinities can be unequal but when approximating the sum of a series, I think there are sufficient terms within $n\rightarrow \frac{\infty}{2}$ in place of $n\rightarrow \infty$   to give approximate correct answer.

**In other words, my answer should atleast be close to the correct answer if not equal.**

Comment: You can't just rearrange conditionally convergent series like that. [That way lies madness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Getting_an_arbitrary_sum).

Comment: Your "contradiction" tells that you cannot manipulate infinites, especially an expression of the form $\infty-\infty$, like ordinary numbers.

Comment: You can pull out any values out of **indeterminates**, an expression of the form like $$\infty-\infty,\qquad\frac{\infty}{\infty},\qquad1^{\infty},\qquad\infty^0,\qquad\text{etc.},$$ if the expression is manipulated carelessly and in a forbidden way. (In short, if you let two infinites compete each other, you can get whatever you want.) Your very first step yields an indeterminate of the form $\infty-\infty$ and hence not a valid operation.

Comment: Never play too much with $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Riemann Rearrangement theorem, you could always rearrange the terms of an infinite series to change its value. The only time you are allowed to rearrange terms like this $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+b_n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$$Is if the two infinite sums on the write converge. In this case your rearrangement doesn't satisfy this condition.

Comment: Why only when the sums on right converge? Why not always?

Comment: This is because $\infty$ doesn't behave like normal numbers. If the sums on the right didn't converge, they would be the same as $\frac12$ times those sums, and when we combine them again a contradiction occurs.

Comment: "you could always rearrange the terms of an infinite series to change its value". This is true if the series is not absolutely convergent

Comment: @SineoftheTime Not necessarily. For example, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(k+1)}$ could be rearranged as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}$. We could multiply $\frac12$ by each of these sums and then recombine to get that $1=\frac12$.